# Regular expression with more than nine pairs of brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regular expression with ten pairs of brackets. With `RegExp.$n` I need to access bracket pair 1, 2 and 10. In JS it's only possible to access the bracket pairs up to number 9. Since I need not to access pairs 3 to 9 is there a way to change the regular expression such those brackets don't count? Then I could access bracket pair 9 by `RegExp.$3`. I'm also happy with any other solution to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The match result is indexable by the group number (where there's always an implicit group `0` for the whole match):

```
> "banana".match(/()()()()()()()()()()(na)+/)[11]
"na"
> "banana".match(/()()()()()()()()()()(na)+/)[0]
"nana"

// Works with exec too
> /()()()()()()()()()()(na)+/.exec("banana")[11]
"na"
```

Note that within `replace()`, there doesn't seem to be a restriction on the group number:

```
> "banana".replace(/()()()()()()()()()()(na)+/, "[$11]")
"ba[na]"
```

To answer the other part of your question -- yes, it is indeed possible to have create what are called *non-capturing groups* using the `(?:foo)` syntax instead of `(foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create non-capturing groups with `?:` for things that you don't need to access later.

```
"rex".match(/(r)(?:e)(x)/)
// ["rex", "r", "x"]
```